# ggplot2: how to remove slash from geom_density legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm trying to plot some overlapping density plots in ggplot2. I'm running into a problem where I cannot remove the diagonal slash from the legend. I have tried using scale_fill_manual() and legend.key as well as the hack from R Cookbook, but I cant seem to get it right.

```
data(iris)
iris=iris
cols=brewer.pal(3,"Set1")

ggplot(iris) + 
    geom_density(position="identity",aes(x=iris$Sepal.Length,fill=cols[1]),
        colour="black",alpha=.5) +
    geom_density(position="identity",aes(x=iris$Sepal.Width,fill=cols[2]),
        colour="black",alpha=.5)+  
    theme_bw() +
    scale_fill_identity(guide="legend",labels=c("Sepal Width","Sepal Length"))+
    xlab("X axis") +
    theme(panel.background=element_blank(),
        legend.title=element_blank(),
        legend.key = element_rect(),
        legend.background = element_blank(),
        legend.justification=c(1,0), 
        legend.position=c(.75,.5),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank())
```

[image]

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try this:

```
+ guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour = NULL)))
```

although that removes the black outline as well...which can be added back in by change the `theme` to:

```
legend.key = element_rect(colour = "black")
```

I completely forgot to add this important note: do **not** specify aesthetics via `x=iris$Sepal.Length` using the `$` operator! That is not the intended way to use `aes()` and it will lead to errors and unexpected problems down the road.

Comment: @Logister No problem. Please do see my additional note, though.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I will adjust my future code.

Comment: Great! I think Hadley should make this the default in fact, or add some option for this! If the R Cookbook devotes a section to this that means something :-)

Comment: This works for the most part, though I've haven't gotten it to work if I have multiple scale_..._...'s. For example, if I have a scale_fill_manual and a scale_alpha_manual, then I can't remove the diagonal lines. Not sure why this is a problem.

Comment: For me, only the very bottom and right borders were rendered in RStudio (Windows), but it looked as expected after `ggsave`ing.