# ggplot2 change colours in bar chart with scale_color_identity()

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I'm using the workaround to remove diagonal lines from a ggplot legend: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ggplot2/vJnF9_HBqx4

With the following data, how do I change the colours of the groups?

```
# Create data #

a<-as.data.frame(c(1,1,1,2,2))
b<-as.data.frame(c("A","A","B","B","A"))
c<-as.data.frame(c(20,20,60,50,50))
a<-cbind(a,b,c)
colnames(a)<-c("X","Gp","Y")

# Plot #

ggplot(a, aes(x=X, y=Y,fill=Gp)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(colour = "black")) + 
  scale_color_identity() + 
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(colour = "black", size = 1))
```

I have tried changing the following elements :

```
scale_color_identity(values=c("red","yellow"))

geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(colour = c("red","yellow")))

geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(colour = "black"), fill=c("red","yellow"))
```

but each produces an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.  The guides call let's you pick which scale to not have a legend.  And, you can set the outline colour without aes().

**EDIT after comment about diagonal line in legend**

Based on this SO question [remove diagonal line in legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25294604/ggplot2-how-to-remove-slash-from-geom-density-legend), you can added the guides(fill etc. call to remove the diagonal.

```
ggplot(a, aes(x=X, y=Y,fill=Gp)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", colour = "black") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red","yellow")) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour = NULL))) +
  guides(colour = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, however this removes the black contour around the bars which I would like to keep, and also adds the unnecessary second legend (the one underneath).

Comment: Have to complete something but I will revert.

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: This was the original method I used, however the goal was to not have the diagonal line in the legend boxes. It seems this is imposible without using default colours.

Answer (score 1):

You can also call `geom_bar` twice. Once for the legend, and without the color argument, and once with the color argument but suppressing the legend

```
 ggplot(a, aes(x=X, y=Y,fill=Gp)) + 
       geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = 'black', show_guide = F) +
       geom_bar(stat = 'identity') + 
       scale_fill_manual(values = c('red', 'yellow') )
```