# Remove slashes from ggplot2 legend using geom_histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

How do you remove the slashes from the legend?

[image]

```
ggplot(data, aes(y, fill = factor(x))) +
geom_histogram(colour = "black", position = 'identity') +
theme(legend.position="top", legend.title=element_blank()) +
scale_fill_manual(values = c(rgb(11,61,145, maxColorValue=255), "white",         rgb(252,61,33, maxColorValue=255))) +
scale_y_continuous("Count") +  
scale_x_continuous("Age") + 
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold", color="#252525", size=12),
  axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", color="#252525", size=12))
```

Thank You.

Comment: this should work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25294787/3283824

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does this work for you?

```
library(ggplot2) 
set.seed(6667)
diamonds_small <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]
ggplot(diamonds_small, aes(price, fill = cut)) +
       geom_density(alpha = 0.2)  +  
       guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour = NULL)))
```

Using example from http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_histogram.html

[image]